# Nginx + Django + Phpmyadmin Configuration

Tags: django, nginx, phpmyadmin

I've migrated my server to amazon ec2, and trying to set up the following environment there:

Nginx in the front serving static content, passing to django for dynamic content. I also would like to use phpmyadmin in this setting.

I am not a server admin, so I simply followed a few tutorials to make nginx and django up and running. But I've been working for two days now trying to hook phpmyadmin to this setup, with no avail. I am sending my current server configuration now, how can I serve phpmyadmin here?

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name localhost;

    access_log /opt/django/logs/nginx/vc_access.log;
    error_log  /opt/django/logs/nginx/vc_error.log;

    # no security problem here, since / is always passed to upstream
    root /opt/django/;
    # serve directly - analogous for static/staticfiles
    location /media/ {
        # if asset versioning is used
        if ($query_string) {
            expires max;
        }
    }
    location /admin/media/ {
        # this changes depending on your python version
        root /path/to/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib;
    }
    location /static/ {
        # if asset versioning is used
        if ($query_string) {
            expires max;
        }
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 10;
        proxy_read_timeout 10;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
    }
    # what to serve if upstream is not available or crashes
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /media/50x.html;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question should rightly belong to http://serverfault.com

Nevertheless, the first thing you ought to do is to configure a separate subdomain for your phpmyadmin for ease of administration.

So there will be two apps running with nginx as reverse proxy, one nginx `server` for your above django app and another `server` (also known as virtualhost) for your phpmyadmin with a configuration similar to this:-

```
server {
         server_name     phpmyadmin.<domain.tld>;
         access_log      /srv/http/<domain>/logs/phpmyadmin.access.log;
         error_log       /srv/http/<domain.tld>/logs/phpmyadmin.error.log;

         location / {
                 root    /srv/http/<domain.tld>/public_html/phpmyadmin;
                 index   index.html index.htm index.php;
         }

         location ~ \.php$ {
                 root            /srv/http/<domain.tld>/public_html/phpmyadmin;
                 fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
                 fastcgi_index   index.php;
                 fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  /srv/http/<domain.tld>/public_html/phpmyadmin/$fastcgi_script_name;
                 include         fastcgi_params;
         }
 }
```

Each of your `server` configuration can point at different domain names via the `server_name` configuration.  In this example, `server_name   phpmyadmin.<domain.tld>;`

Here's an example taken from http://wiki.nginx.org/ServerBlockExample

```
http {
  index index.html;

  server {
    server_name www.domain1.com;
    access_log logs/domain1.access.log main;

    root /var/www/domain1.com/htdocs;
  }

  server {
    server_name www.domain2.com;
    access_log  logs/domain2.access.log main;

    root /var/www/domain2.com/htdocs;
  }
}
```

As you can see, there are two declarations of `server` inside the large `http` brackets.  Each declaration of the `server` should contain the configuration you have for django and another for the configuration of phpmyadmin.

2 "virtual hosts" ("server" instances) taken care by nginx.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I am a complete newbie on the subject, could you be more specific? Do I need to create two configuration files? Do I need to do something else to run them as reverse proxy?